# How do I multiply values from different inputs to get a total using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, shopping-cart, multiplication

I am trying to do a shopping cart where I want the total to automatically change after the quantity is inputted (the total is the price times the quantity). I'm trying to use Javascript for this and I just can't seem to get it as it is coming up with null and before it said NaN.

PS: It is a console log at the moment just to see if it works, but I will need it to go into the total input tag.

HTML:

```
<input id="price" type="text" readonly value="$18.95">
<input id="quantity" type="text" value="1" onchange="calcTotal()">
<input id="total" type="text" readonly value="$18.95">
```

JavaScript:

```
function calcTotal() {
  var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  var total = price * quantity;
  console.log(total);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect for `"$18.95" * "1"`? You should be multiplying numbers, not String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function calcTotal() {
// remove $ sign and parse Float price
  var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value.substr(1));
 // parse float quantity
  var quantity = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
  var total = price * quantity;
  //pass calculated value to input with id total
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total;
}
```

```html
<input id="price" type="text" readonly value="$18.95">
<input id="quantity" type="text" value="1" onchange="calcTotal()">
<input id="total" type="text" readonly value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Any operation that involves a string  returns `NaN`, however you should 
coerce your input values as  `Number`

```
function calcTotal() {
  var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  var total =Number(price) * Number(quantity);
  console.log(total);
}
```

**Using `Number` vs `parseFloat`**

So as long as you have standard numeric input, there's no difference. However, if your input starts with a number and then contains other characters, parseFloat truncates the number out of the string, while Number gives NaN (not a number):

```
parseFloat('1x'); // => 1
Number('1x'); // => NaN
```